# Compare the bcrypt password with plain text password

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i have stored the password by using Bcrypt hashcode in database table, but i want to validate that password once the user loggin to my application.

Problem i'm facing is when user login , i'm getting password in plain text form , so how should i compare this with the database password.

My application is completed based on spring boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing this :

```
 PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();     
 if(passwordEncoder.matches(plainTextPassword,encryptedPassword)) {
     // process
 }
```

Comment: Hi Yosra, Its works for me just by doing small changes, instead of using PasswordEncoder referance , i'm using BCryptPasswordEncoder  referance ,     
                                                                                                   
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();     
 if(passwordEncoder.matches(plainTextPassword,encryptedPassword)) {
     // process
 }

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the same "Bcrypt hashcode" algorithm that you applied during the signup phase in the login phase. And afterwards just compare it with the value stored in the database. 
In case the equals matches you will let the request follow it's follow, and otherwise throw an exception.

There's no other way since :

> Hashing performs a one-way transformation on a password, turning the password into another String, called the hashed password. “One-way” means that it is practically impossible to go the other way - to turn the hashed password back into the original password.
>   [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGPersProgGuide/html/s0506passwordhashing01.html)

Please check this on how to use [BCrypt for registration and login in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt)

Comment: Hi Andrei, thanks for suggestion , but i got to know that hashcode generated is not same ,i mean for same string the hashcode can be different , so i guess we can't compare like this.

Comment: Hi Kumar, please check the edit that I made. I added a link with working example for registration and signUp that will solve your problem. Btw the generate hascode from two identical strings must be the same

Comment: Hi Andrei, thanks for all shared resources. I tried for identical string, it geneated different hashcode each time.

Comment: I really don't understand how using **new BCryptPasswordEncoder()**, from the link that I suggested doesn't work. I think you're not doing something wrongly.